# Return image from actions in Rasa x

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-x

I’m doing like that:

```py
dispatcher.utter_message(image='https://dvtb78sd925mn.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/15110630/exemplo-marketing-derelacionamento.png')
```

But rasa x is not showing the image

Comment: It might be because of there is some problem in package installation or it's dependencies (e.g. `numpy` or `matplotlib`). Is it installed correctly?

Comment: Yes! In rasa shell works, returns a image link, but in the rasa x don't. @mrzrm

Answer (score 0):

For the record (I'm guessing you know about these): Forum post here https://forum.rasa.com/t/return-image-from-actions-in-rasa-x/25643/6 suggests this is a bug; bug opened here https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/5388

Answer (score 0):

We can return an image from a custom action server in RASA-X. I have used the below code to return an image from a custom action server. In actions.py file,
use the below statement

```
dispatcher.utter_message(text="Test Image",image="http://localhost:7000/img/charts/TestImage.png")
return []
```

RASA-X Version : "0.42.0"

RASA : "2.8.0"